# Set ComboBox to ID of another ComboBox

Tags: c++, mfc, ccombobox

I am currently trying to set a CComboBox* with the ID that is assigned for existing combo box(IDC_COMBO).

I've tried CWnd's GetDlgItem() and ID assignment, but I could not figure it out yet.

I know this isn't exactly the expected details, but this is all I can give you.

Comment: [`CWnd::SetDlgCtrlID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a22k62xy.aspx) - if you are to change identifier of actual window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
CComboBox* pCombo = reinterpret_cast<CComboBox*>(GetDlgItem (IDC_COMBO));
```

Comment: YES! Thank you very much! I was banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out, and here you have the answer! Thank you again. Brilliant.